# How to get html-elements from html string?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, objective-c

I need to get an image and its title from html string. I heard, javascript may get elements via tags or ids, but I've never used javascript earlier. So I found a nice framework - `JavaScriptCore` and here's my code snippet:

```
JSContext* context = [[JSContext alloc] initWithVirtualMachine:[JSVirtualMachine new]];
NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var parser = new DOMParser();"
                          "var doc = parser.parseFromString(%@, \"text/html\");"
                          "var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');", [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""]];
[context evaluateScript:jsString];
```

But `context[@"parser"]`, `context[@"doc"]` and `context[@"imgs"]` return `undefined`. What do I make wrong? Maybe I will be better to use some other approach without `JavaScriptCore`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use some third party library that supports XPath queries. IMHO that would be a better way to work with DOM.

Here's a link with example  http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios

Comment: Your link use `NSXMLDocument` which is only of OS X

Comment: @ValentinShamardin I'm sorry, my bad. I've misread the question. Updated an answer. Thank you for pointing it out

Comment: Yes, I saw this link, thank you. Thank you for your time, I vote up.